# Why type constraint on base class does not show default interface implementation?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

In C# 8.0, the default interface implementation was introduced.
Now you could write an interface like this

```
interface IFoo{
   void DoDefaultThing(){
   // Do some default stuff here
   }

   void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

And the class implements it

```
public Foo: IFoo{
  public void DoSomethingElse(){
  // Implementation
  }
}
```

Currently, I have a generic method with the type constraint on `Foo`

```
public void UseFoo<T>(T foo) where T:Foo{
  foo.DoSomethingElse();//Valid
  foo.DoDefaultThing();//Compiler error
}
```

I could work around this restriction by adding the interface constraint

```
public void UseFoo<T>(T foo) where T:Foo,IFoo{
  foo.DoSomethingElse();//Valid
  foo.DoDefaultThing();//Now Valid
}
```

Is this somehow the compiler limitation?

Comment: No, this is correct. The default interface implementation is *not* a method of `Foo`; it is accessible only through `IFoo` references. This is not specific to generics. You don't need to make the constraint more complicated; `((IFoo) foo).DoDefaultThing()` will work.

Comment: I'm under the impression that default interface implementation is the way to introduce new method to a type without introducing breaking change in the same manner that extension method does. It makes sense to me now why it behaves like this.